# How to boot to Windows 10 after Server Core 2016 installation

Tags: iis, windows-server, server-core

I installed Server Core 2016 (without the GUI) onto my Windows 10 computer.

Now, whenever I boot up the computer, it just opens a single command prompt with Server Core commands.

How do I go back to Windows 10?